# How to change values in a dictionary from a string to an integer and back again?

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary, integer

I have a dictionary like this:

```
d = {(1,1):'.',(2,2):'b', (3,3):'1',(4,4):'2',(5,5):'3'}
```

and i want to be able to iterate over the items in the dictionary, check if a key's value is a number (it is currently a string type but I need to check if said string is actually a numeral not a dot or letter) and add to that value,
as in value += 1.

I need to return the dictionary with it's key's values back in string form.

What's the best way to change the values from a string type to an integer (in order to add +1) and back into a string so that the returned dictionary will look like this?:

```
d = {(1,1):'.',(2,2):'b', (3,3):'2',(4,4):'3',(5,5):'4'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = {(1,1):'.',(2,2):'b', (3,3):'1',(4,4):'2',(5,5):'3'}
>>> {k:(str(int(v)+1) if v.isdigit() else v) for k, v in d.items()}
{(2, 2): 'b', (1, 1): '.', (4, 4): '3', (5, 5): '4', (3, 3): '2'}
>>>
```

You  could use dictionary comprehensions for this where in you can check if the value comprises of digits then return +1 value else return as it is.

Comment: It's always good to explain what your answer *actually does* when posting, this way OP can learn from it.

Comment: doing this does return a dictionary with the values increased by 1, but I needed the values returned as strings, not just integers

Comment: @M.Pro you can type cast it to string